# Data Management and Visualisation for specific Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, visualization

So, i have been thinking about this long enough to ask for help now, since i am not too good with R yet.
I have a data frame that looks as follow:

Genre, Hit, Year, n (for number of appearance)

For Example

1. Sci-Fi 2. Wäldchen 3. 1950 4. 2

- First thing i want is to see a specific hit over the whole period of time, so all years accumulated, leaving the genre out, since its not important here. I just want for one hit (here a specific word) to see all occurences over the years (eg. 5 hits in 1951, 3 in 1952, 0 in 1953) and so on
  So far if i used this command (i dont need the Context, URL, Bibl and exact date (just the year))

daten.redux2 <- select(daten.raw, -ContextBefore, -ContextAfter,
-URL, -Bibl, -Date, -Genre)

i can get rid of the Genre, but the data still shows me separate hits for one word (since they are their own hit in the data, but it is the same word and i do not need it broken down into single hits-for better understanding: I just want to know how many times this word occured in one whole year overall, NOT where it occured every single time)

Second thing is i want to visualize this use of a hit over the period of time (my data goes for 50 years). Best here would probably be something like a histogram, or could i also use a raincloud?

I would be very thankful for help!

Tried to kick out the "Genre" but it still gives single hits not accumulated for one word for the whole year

Comment: To make it easier for people to help you, please provide some example data as code that we can load. One simple way is to run `dput(head(YOUR_DATA))` and copy all the output into the body of your question. It would also help if you could describe what libraries you are using. `select` suggests you might be using `dplyr`?

Comment: Using dplyr, `daten.raw |> distinct(Hit, Year)` would output a row for each distinct Hit-Year combination found in the data.

Comment: Asking for general data visualization advice is off topic here. Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions. For data viz advice you might try a site like [stats.se] instead. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.